# why eight httpd processes?

Tags: apache2

I am using linux EC2, I see 8 httpd processes **immediately** after I start apache, 2 of which are owned by root and the rest are owned by 'apache':

```
root     22966     1  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     22968 22966  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22969 22966  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22970 22966  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22971 22966  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22972 22966  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22973 22966  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   22974 22966  0 08:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Why are there 8 processes? I assumed this has something to do with the prefork/worker configuration, probably prefork, but my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file looks like this, and nowhere is 8 or 6 defined, maybe I am missing something?

```
# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# ServerLimit: maximum value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the server
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers      5
MinSpareServers   3
MaxSpareServers  9
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: StartServers + MinSpareServers ?

Comment: i thought StartServers include MinSpare, no?

Comment: Well maybe, yeah. Can you try [tweaking the numbers and see what happens](http://xkcd.com/242/) ?

Comment: Refer : https://serverfault.com/questions/272296/why-do-i-have-so-many-apache2-processes